# How would you make a request when you created a form?

Tags: javascript, http, post, request, forms

I am trying to hack a page that requires a "username" and "password". I have created a form and I think it looks good;

```
  <form action="http://hackmefff.co/login">
  <input type="hidden" name = "username" value="hacker">
  <input type="hidden" name = "password" value="b678jk">
  </form>
```

People have told me that my form looks good and that I need to create a request in javascript. I don't know how to create one because I just started learning javascript yesterday. I have searched on how to create a request of submit, and all I see is functions that look like they are making a form, which I already have, so am confused. How would I send a request to log me into a website, assuming that url exists, and both name and password are correct.

EDIT:
I have formatted the code below because I don't want the page to show any text at all even though am logged in, it should just be blank. But a test page shows that I didn't get logged in;

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">

<html>
    <head>
      <title>Test page for your custom form</title>
      <script type="text/javascript">
        function submitform()
        {
           document.yourform.submit();
        }
      </script>
   </head>
  <body>
    <form name="yourform" action="http://hackmefff.co/login">
      <input type="hidden" name = "username" value="hacker">
      <input type="hidden" name = "password" value="b678jk">
    </form>
    <input type='hidden' name='query' />
    <a href="javascript: submitform()"></a>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: you try send it to javascript??? or php/asp??

Comment: If this request can be accessed via a `GET`, then you could just type the following directly into your web browser address bar: http://hackmefff.co/login?username=your_username&password=your_password

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test page for your custom form</title>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function submitform()
            {
               document.yourform.submit();
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form name="yourform" action="http://hackmefff.co/login" method="post">
        <input type="hidden" name = "username" value="hacker">
        <input type="hidden" name = "password" value="b678jk">
        </form>
        Search: <input type='text' name='query' />
        <a href="javascript: submitform()">Login</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Note that I have modified your `form` slightly to include a `name` so that we can reference it from the JavaScript function.

This answer of course assumes that you have to use JavaScript.

Comment: Hi Tim, I have added an edit in the question, plz look at it. For some reason I tried on a test page where I know the my username and password and didn't get logged in

Comment: Please try using the JavaScript/net console in your browser by pressing F12.  It will show you whether the request went out as a GET or POST, as well as possibly other useful feedback for what went wrong with your login.

Comment: This is good, but couldn't work for me. i ended up doing something else, now looking back on this, I think you're missing a "post".

Comment: I just added `method="post"` to the `<form>` tag in my sample code.  Can you test this and make another comment if it still doesn't work?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need Javascript for that, just add a submit-button to your form:

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
```